# type va_list representation in memory

Tags: c

After reading [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start%20%22%22) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_va_start.htm%20%22%22), I understand that

```
void va_start(va_list ap, last);
```

Saves in `va_list pa` some information about arguments whose number and types are not known to the called function. Later arguments can be extracted via `va_arg()`.

Documentation doesn't specify how things are put in `va_list pa`

In short: I need to know how its being saved in memory. Its memory representation.

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int, ...);

int main(void)
{
   printf("Sum of 10, 20 and 30 = %d\n",  sum(3, 10, 20, 30) );
       return 0;
}

int sum(int num_args, ...)
{
   int val = 0;
   va_list ap;
   int i;

   va_start(ap, num_args);
   for(i = 0; i < num_args; i++)
   {
      val += va_arg(ap, int);
   }
   va_end(ap);

   return val;
}
```

What information is stored in pa ? how does it look in memory for the above example ?
And how from the above example it knows the type is `int` and not something else ?

Comment: Any code relying on a specific implementation of `va_list` is broken by design. Just only use the functions/macros provided. Wrt how it knows the type: did you notice the second argument to `va_arg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implementation-dependent. Sometimes, `va_list` is simply `char*`. Basically, `ap` represents an array of pointers to chars. When calling `va_arg(ap, TYPE)` it reads memory from address at which `ap` points, but it reads it as `TYPE` type. So, if you call it with `int` it will read 4 bytes and convert it to `int` type.

Comment: Are the numbers stored `last to first` or `first to last`. I mean if I print the first number, should I get the first argument or the last argument ?

Comment: @TonyTannous. They are stored first to last. But, notice that they are not consecutively stored in memory, but instead their pointers are stored in array.

Comment: @Olaf. First of all, I said it is **implementation-dependent**, so you cannot talk about its ABI. At least, it is used in some compilers. Moreower, I answered OP's question correctly, but what you are talking about is something related to implementation details. BTW, thanks for downvote :)

Comment: You argue that I comment on an answer about **implementation details** an implementation detail you qualify as "usually" is not typical? Oh, and it is in to specified by the compiler. I intentionally used the term ABI. That **is** an implementation detail.

Comment: @Olaf. Ok, if you insist, I changed word `usually` to `sometimes`. Anyway, OP understood my answer and it helped him. As you can see it is accepted, which mean it is helpful. What you are trying to do is bothering with details. Anyone can open Wikipedia and read details, I just explained basic concept of how it works.

Comment: You did notice your last sentence covers the problem, didn't you?

Comment: @Olaf. I'm not sure what are you talking about. What exactly do you want me to fix in my answer?